# Is it possible bean mapping to resultset as apache dbutils in jodd?

Tags: java, jodd

I'm using the jodd framework and it provides lots of utility with `dboom`.

My question is, can I do simple pojo mapping to a result set like `ResultSetHandler` by apache dbutils with the jodd dboom module?

sql query :

```
select child.id as id, child.name as name, parent.name as parentCategoryName
from tblmcategory child left outer join tblmcategory parent
on parent.categoryId = child.parentCategoryId;`
```

and pojo is like

```
public class CategoryData implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String parentCategoryName;

    //setter and getters method....
}
```

can I map resultset to this pojo list..?

dao code ::

```
public <T> List<T> executeQuery1(String query, Class<T> clazz) throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            return jodd.db.oom.DbOomQuery.query(query).autoClose().list(clazz);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

From this I am getting correct count in list but it is list of null object....

Comment: Yes you can have simple bean mapping. Please note that on [SO] you should ask more concrete questions.

Comment: Yes i know but i want pojo mapping without any dbtable or dbcolumn annotation like please see my updated question.

Comment: You dont have to use annotation, just simple beans, and follow the naming convention (that even can be set:). But if you want to use aliases, you just have to register the beans manually, that is all. If you want just mapping, you dont have to register anything :)

Comment: please see code where i am passing query and dataclass type.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Jodd DbOom Naming Strategies](http://jodd.org/doc/db/mapping.html#naming-strategies). In DbOoom it is possible to register or configure your own naming strategy, that define how column names are converted to bean names. In your case this is what happens: since you have `null` objects in the list, this means that mapping failed.

Default mapping rule/convention is the following: column name `FOO_BAR` is translated to `fooBar`. You are using different naming strategy, where column name equals to bean name.

So you can do the following:

- change the strategy to match your use case, or
- rename database columns to common 'uppercase-with-underscore-separated-names' :)